# How to emulate Android with Xamarin in an Azure VM?

Tags: android, visual-studio, azure, xamarin, hyper-v

I've been struggling to have my Xamarin project running in an Azure VM with Visual Studio 2015 and Xamarin. The error it gives me is:

```
The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'VS Emulator 5-inch KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone.dawud' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running (Virtual machine ID <id_number>.
```

I have read I need to enable nested virtualization in Hyper-V, but as this is an Azure machine I don't think I can do it.

Do you know what else I can do?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use Xamarin with any android emulators, such as [http://www.bluestacks.com/](http://www.bluestacks.com/).

Comment: I have tried the: https://towardsdatascience.com/android-emulator-on-azure-vm-fe4df57a6955. But replacing the opengl.dll causes a crash when starting android emulator from visual studio